# Surface 3 w Win10 -- audio stopped working, troubleshooter sees issue but does not fix

Tags: audio, microsoft-surface

All audio playback.... is silent. Via built in speakers and via headphone jack.

No issues in the OS are visible. It thinks audio is there and happy.

MS has an audio troubleshooter that goes through a diag and repair process... but no change. Audio is still hosed.

I guesstimate that a recent win10 update caused the issue (but am not sure).

How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it as follows:

Uninstall the audio driver
Reboot
OS detects the audio and automatically reinstalls driver

Tada... audio works.